# $resource invalidation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this use case where I pass authToken to every request and this token changes everytime the person logins.

```
app.factory('Comment', function ($resource, localStorageService, $cacheFactory) {
return $resource('http://localhost:port/comments/:id', {"id":"@id", port:':9000'}, {
    query: { method:'GET', isArray: true , headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+localStorageService.get("authToken")}},
    save: { method:'POST',headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+localStorageService.get("authToken")}},
    update: {method:'PUT' ,headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+localStorageService.get("authToken")}},
    delete : {method: 'DELETE',headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+localStorageService.get("authToken")}},
    get : { method: 'GET', headers: {'X-AUTH-TOKEN':'authToken='+localStorageService.get("authToken")}}
});
```

The behaviour I am seeing is that if the authToken changes for some reason the $resource keeps adding the previous authToken while sending the request.  I am using the $http directly for login and for any commenting related stuff I am using $resource. Am I missing something?

After login I make sure that my localStorage has the newly created token but the request are using the previous authToken till I refresh the page after which it adds the correct header I know that the $resource uses some kind of caching and tried to remove the $http cache like this after loggin in.

```
$cacheFactory.get('$http').removeAll();
```

but didnt't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because token is assigned once when factory code executes. Try this instead:

```
get : { method: 'GET', headers: {
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN': function(){
        return 'authToken=' + localStorageService.get("authToken");
    }
}}
```